# How to prevent message redelivery from MQ Broker after camel internal redeliveries are successfully processed (transacted camel route)

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-transactions, camel-jms

I am trying to run a camel transacted() route (a standalone java process) with JPATransactionManager is the spring PlatformTransactionManager (as I want camel route to run in a single DB transaction) but I am not able to suppress redelivery from MQ Broker in case a transactional method fails even though I have used handled(true) in onException clause along with my custom redelivery policy (which is executed successfully). I only want MQ to redeliver when there is a service crash.

Tried below but it doesn't work:

- Setting setTransacted(false) in JMSComponent config so as to prevent camel jms to run is transacted_session jms mode but it does not work
- doTry and doCatch the exception from transactional block
- camel redeliveries followed by handled(true).

  ```
  onException(Exception.class)
      .log("ERROR OCCURRED")
      .redeliveryPolicyRef("myRedeliveryPolicy")
      .handled(true)
      .to(getPostExceptionRoute());

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public RedeliveryPolicy myRedeliveryPolicy() {
      RedeliveryPolicy myRedeliveryPolicy= new RedeliveryPolicy();
      myRedeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(2);
      myRedeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveryDelay(2000);
      return myRedeliveryPolicy;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public JmsComponent jms(IJMSConnectionFactory cf) throws JMSException {
      JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
      jmsComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfig(cf));
      jmsComponent.setTransacted(false);
      return jmsComponent;
  }

  from("jms:queue:TestQueue?acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE")
      .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, TestObject.class)
      .transacted()
      .processRef("myPersistInDBProcessor")
  ```
- I expect camel to try redeliveries as per redelivery policy (working) but MQ should not redeliver.
- I expect my camel route to run in a single db transaction.
- I expect MQ broker to redeliver only when my java service crashes in middle of processing, so that I do not lose the message.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect camel to try redeliveries as per redelivery policy (working) but MQ should not redeliver

When MQ **must never** do a redelivery (because you handle errors in Camel), you should remove `acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` or explicitly set `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` (default value).

As long as a message is not acknowledged, it is from the broker perspective not delivered. `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` immediately acknowledges the message after consumption what makes sense if you **never** want to get redeliveries.

`CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` on the other hand only acknowledges a message under certain conditions, see [this post for some more info about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498652/camel-jms-client-acknowledge-mode).

#### EDIT due to comment with new information

If you want MQ redeliveries, but "override" them with Camel in most cases, you have to **consume messages transacted**.

Use **local JMS broker transactions** by configuring your JMS component like this

```
jmsComponent.setLazyCreateTransactionManager(false);
jmsComponent.setTransacted(true);
```

For this type of transaction you don't need a Spring TransactionManager at all. So I guess the `JPATransactionManager` is **ignored by JMS** and your JMS consumptions should be transactional.

Now, when your Camel error handler "swallows" an Exception by using `handled(true)`, there must be no MQ redelivery. But MQ does a redelivery when an Exception is propagated back to the broker.

> I expect my camel route to run in a single db transaction

I did not find anything in your question about not working database transactions. There seems to be just one processor that does database stuff. If this is not working correctly, please describe the problem in your question or a separate question.

Comment: I only want MQ to redeliver in case of java service crash which I won't be able to achieve with AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE MODE. Single db transaction part is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apache Karaf Transaction Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.3/html/apache_karaf_transaction_guide/camel-application) should doTry and doCatch work as expected. What is probably the problem in your case is the Exception triggering the error scenario. Only [checked exceptions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.3/html/apache_karaf_transaction_guide/camel-application#error-handling-and-rollbacks) (no RuntimeException or it's descendant) don't mark ongoing transaction for rolling back.