# Camel: Routing from queue to HTTP

Tags: apache-camel

Bit of a Camel newbie but here goes.

I have the following route:

```
    from("activemq:queue:outputQueue").inputType(HelloWorld.class)
    .to("log:stream")
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, HelloWorld.class)
    .to("http:localhost:5000/messageForYouSir?bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

This retrieves messages from the queue and sends them to the HTTP endpoint as JSON. Fine.

But what if there is an error? Say a HTTP error code of 400? Then I want the message to stay on the queue. I have tried looking into not acknowledging the message, but have not been able to make it work.

Also I have made an Exception handler

```
    onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
    .handled(false)
    .setBody().constant("Vi fekk ein feil");
```

But still the messages are gone from the queue. Is there some magic spell that can make Camel not acknowledge the messages when there is some error?

Comment: Not ACKing the message is the way to go. Did you have a look at [this question already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498652/camel-jms-client-acknowledge-mode)

Comment: Yeah, I did. But doesn't seem to work. Tried the URL activemq:queue:outputQueue?acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE but the queue is emptied.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **consume transacted** from the queue to be able to do a rollback. This is configured on the connection configuration to the broker.

Take a look at the [Camel JMS docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html) (the ActiveMQ component extends the JMS component), especially the sections about [cache levels](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html#_transactions_and_cache_levels) and [transacted consumption](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html#_enabling_transacted_consumption).

The most simple setup is using **broker transactions** by simply set `transacted = true` and `lazyCreateTransactionManager = false` on the `JmsConfiguration`. This way no Spring TX manager is required.

If transacted consumption is in place and the HTTP server returns an error (basically if an Exception occurs in the Camel Route), **Camel does automatically a rollback** (if you don't catch the error).